# PyQt5 window.close() does no close the window but window.open() works fine

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I'm using PyQt5 QWebEngineView to show a website on the window that supports basic functionalities like opening a new window.
My code works fine for window.open() but for window.close() function on a webpage it removes the reference to the window but the window is physically there unless the user manually closes the window.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


class MyWindow(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):

    currentFile = ''

    def __init__(self,windows, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self._windows = windows
        self._windows.append(self)


        self.load(QUrl("https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_close"))
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)  
        self.show()

    def createWindow(self, windows):
        print(windows)
        if windows == QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.WebBrowserTab:
            webView = MyWindow(self._windows)
            webView.resize(900, 780) # <----
            return webView

        elif windows == QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.WebDialog:
            webView = MyWindow(self._windows)
            webView.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)           
            webView.resize(900, 780) # <----

            webView.show()          
            return webView

        elif windows == QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.acceptNavigationRequest:
            webView = MyWindow(self._windows)
            webView.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)           
            webView.resize(900, 780) # <----
            webView.show()          
            return webView
        return super(MyWindow, self).createWindow(windows)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    windows = []
    main = MyWindow(windows)  
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When the user clicks on the button with function window.close() the window is still there but is refrenced from the stack (I know this cause that page does not work)

Comment: There are no methods `open` or `close` in this code. I don’t understand what you are talking about.

Comment: its a javascript functions which is used to open and close the new window.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup a QWebEnginePage for the QWebEngineView and bind the QWebEnginePage.windowCloseRequested to a function as follow:

```
import sys
import os

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui
# from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
# from PyQt5.QtGui import QDesktopServices


class MyWindow(QWebEngineView):

    def __init__(self, windows, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self._windows = windows
        self._windows.append(self)

        # Path
        scriptdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

        # Profile
        self.profile = QWebEngineProfile().defaultProfile()
        self.profile.setPersistentCookiesPolicy(QWebEngineProfile.ForcePersistentCookies)
        self.browser_storage_folder = scriptdir + os.path.sep + '/.cookies'
        self.profile.setPersistentStoragePath(self.browser_storage_folder)

        # Page
        self.page = QWebEnginePage(self.profile, self)
        self.setPage(self.page)

        self.load(QUrl("https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_close"))

        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print('Close Event')

    def CloseRequest(self):
        self.webView.close()
        print('close')

    def createWindow(self, windows):
        print(windows)
        if windows == QWebEnginePage.WebBrowserTab:
            webView = MyWindow(self._windows)
            webView.resize(900, 780)
            return webView

        elif windows == QWebEnginePage.WebDialog:
            webView = MyWindow(self._windows)
            webView.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
            page = QWebEnginePage(self)
            page.windowCloseRequested.connect(self.CloseRequest)
            webView.setPage(page)
            webView.resize(900, 780)
            webView.show()
            self.webView = webView
            return webView

        elif windows == QWebEnginePage.acceptNavigationRequest:
            webView = MyWindow(self._windows)
            webView.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
            webView.resize(900, 780)
            webView.show()
            return webView
        return super(MyWindow, self).createWindow(windows)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    windows = []
    main = MyWindow(windows)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```